# Android Studio no longer recognizes LG G Stylo

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7

I need to know how to make Windows 7 forget it ever connected to my LG G Stylo phone. I have three devices that I use in Android Studio development. For some reason, this one is no longer being detected by the ADB. Something has happened to make it no longer show up, because it did a couple of weeks ago.
AS's ADB will detect my other two devices, and this device shows up in the in the ADB on another computer. I have tediously gone through the registry and removed everything referencing the Stylo, but it still will not show up in AS's ADB.
Thanks for the help!
John

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is thus off-topic for this site.  You are more likely to find an answer on our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Ummm... Why would getting Android Studio's ADB to recognize a debugging device not be a programming issue? Just sayin'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, I have just purchased the LG Stylo 3 plus and ran right into this situation.  TO repeat the basics you need

With Android Studio shut down...

1. Turn on Developer options (tap 7 times on build number in settings
2. (Settings>System>About Phone>Build Number
3. Turn on USB Debugging in Developer Options
4. (optionally) check on the type of USB connection, MTP or PTP should
   work
5. (Optionally) Because I did it, also do a revoke USB tap.

Here was the key for me.  I needed to install the LG USB Windows Drivers for my Windows 7 (I'll try 10 tonight and update).  Go to this page

[LG Drivers and firmware](http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers#)

and either type in model number or browse to find device.  LG has a nice interface to install the Windows Drivers.  I recommend the Support tool to verify the device as the up to date drivers as well.  Start Android Studio and to test I just started the app in debug mode and went through the process of setting up ADB for using the new;y connected device.

Comment: Installing the drivers mentioned by j.hull `LG Drivers and firmware` worked for VS2019 deployment to my LG Stylo.

Comment: Installed LG Mobile Driver worked for me https://gsmusbdriver.com/lg-stylo-5

Answer (score 0):

Developer options" has to be ON in order to make AS see the device

If even though device manager you can't saw the device, Windows couldn't find drivers.Maybe the drivers are hidden on the device otherwise download it and install it.

If that doesn't work:

Shut down

Hit F8 (or whatever gets to startup options screen on your computer)

Disable Driver Signature Enforcement.

Run driver

Comment: As I said, other devices work on this computer, and this device shows up on other computers. I know how to configure things.

Comment: Maybe sound too easy but did you "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" from Developer options